# how to make page scroll more smooth with Waypoints animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I have a few sections on my page with Waypoints css3 animations on them. You can reach the sections either by clicking the menu link or by scrolling down and I want Waypoints to fire in both cases.

The thing is that having sections: About, Services, Prices, Gallery, Team etc. and let's say clicking Gallery, I don't want the previous sections to fire as the page doesn't scroll smooth at all.

So far I managed to write this (and so on for other sections):

```
var prices = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById('prices'),
        handler: function(direction) {
          // animations in the section
        },
        offset: 410
      });
```

and so on for other sections. Then I disable Waypoints on the previous sections if the clicked menu item is further down the road:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    var nameOfLink = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');

    if(nameOfLink == 'prices') {
      Waypoint.disableAll();
      navbar.enable();
      prices.enable();
    }
    if(nameOfLink == 'gallery') {
      Waypoint.disableAll();
      navbar.enable();
      gallery.enable();
    }
    if(nameOfLink == 'team') {
      Waypoint.disableAll();
      navbar.enable();
      team.enable();
    }
```

And here's the smooth scroll code:

```
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top -104
    }, 1000);
    return false;
```

});

It works, for sure more smooth than before, but still not as smooth as I would like it to be (and as I saw it working on other websites).

How can I make it more effective?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options to reach your desired level of 'smoothness' when using the `animate()` function:

**1)** You can modify the `easing` function used in the animation (default easing is `swing`), this is most likely what you will need to modify to get the result you're looking for, for example:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top -104
}, 1000, 'easeInOutQuart');
```

The full list of easing options can be found [here*](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/).

**2)** You can also modify the `duration`
    parameter of the `animate()` function to control the speed of the
    scroll (how long it should take to complete the animation in
    milliseconds).

> *Requires the inclusion of the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library.